# Answered a deleted question

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-questions

Ok, this is my first question on meta subjects so bear with me :)

So, I happened to see a question. Trying to understand what exactly is the problem, I started asking for further info on comments. Than, I realized what's wrong and posted an answer to this question, which the question owner accepted and than I got some reputation points for it respectively.

Only that the cause of error wasn't because of what this person initially thought was the problem, so the title of this question wasn't really suitable for what went wrong.

1 minute after my comments got +1 and my answer got accepted, the user who asked the question and accepted my answer commented something similar to:

```
Thanks! you're right. Uh, This is embarrassing, I should delete this question.
It wasn't what I thought that was a problem.
```

following that, I believe the question got deleted as I don't see it anymore. Furthermore, my reputation points granted for this answer were taken away.

1) What's the benefit out of deleting this question? What other users in the community may learn from this? How will users who encounter the very same problem in the future benefit from this? I'm assuming he won't post another detailed question about this and answer it himself after his issue was resolved.

2) I understand much thought was/is put about the reputation mechanism. Isn't this really de-motivating? from the user who posts the answers point of view - in order to properly assist this person I had to read his code, and try to close in on the problem with him. I took the time and effort in doing this, And than the reputation is taken away?

Comment: Was your answer upvoted?

Comment: No, just accepted as the right answer.

Comment: Ok, then it was probably the asker that deleted it. They couldn't have deleted it if your answer had a positive score, and the whole point of that requirement is that there's little reason to delete on topic questions with good answers.

Comment: In your [reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1555863/user1555863?tab=reputation) there's a "show removed posts" checkbox at the end. If you click it, the system will show you log entries for rep changes on deleted posts. One of them would be for the rep you lost because of this, which will include the name of the question. Please include that name in your question here, to help moderators find the deleted question a bit faster.

Comment: From my humble experience, I guess it takes time to get upvotes to an answer as more users see it and it's somewhat helpful to them. In this case it was deleted minutes after it was asked. I checked the 'show removed posts' checkbox, still don't see it. Add it here if you do.

Comment: find the link and we can vote to undelete

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see removed posts in your profile. No worries, moderators can see them, and won't have much trouble finding the question in question.

Comment: @user1555863 have a look here for the link: http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/1555863

Comment: Related feature request: [Preventing misuse of question self-deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155933/162704)

Comment: @Yannis I can't see it either (not even a 10k link), but I think OP can (it's from the "recently deleted posts link" on user profile with my id replaced with OP's)

Comment: @hayd Ah, that's... smart ;) However, does that also show questions the user have answered, or only those they've asked? Because the OP here is an answerer, not an asker.

Comment: @hayd this links echos `No deleted recent questions`. Thanks @Yannis, I guess this is already well documented. I wonder if there are better ways to address this issue.

Comment: dang (well it would do, it's an answer, somewhat less smart!)

Comment: @hayd: That page lists deleted questions the user asked, not deleted questions that the user answered. In other words, it won't list deleted answers..

Comment: @hayd hello , Even I answered a question which was deleted minutes after the question was asked , I was just in midst of editing the answer when the question was deleted by OP. I thought it will be helpful, the question just got 2 downvotes and he deleted it without waiting for someone to answer. I would appreciate if you would suggest something ... this is the link --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873083/merge-sort-c289-error-subscripted-value-is-neither-array-nor-pointer-nor-vec?noredirect=1#comment26098313_17873083 .... I have read that deleted answers move towards an automatic ban.