# Can we implement a "Your Open Questions" section on the sidebar?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, unanswered-questions, sidebar

[Asked first in WordPress.StackExchange.com](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2538/can-we-implement-a-your-open-questions-section-on-the-sidebar):

When a user is logged in, can we implement a sidebar widget displaying his/her Open Questions for quick browsing or attention?

```
+-------------------------------------+
| YOUR OPEN QUESTIONS                 |
|   Questions those are not answered  |
|   or any of the answer is accepted  |
|   by you.                           |
|                                     |
| * The Question #3 [x]               |
| * The elaborated and detailed       |
|   question #14 [x]                  |
| * Question #32 [x]                  |
|                                     |
|                  All My Questions » |
+-------------------------------------+
```

The criteria of choosing such question automatically can be either:

- A Question by the author, never answered
- A Question by the author, was answered, but none of the answer is marked *Accepted* by the author

The system can automatically remove any Question from the list, if:

- A Question asked by the author, was answered, and Is Accepted by the author.

Flexibility by the user:

- Author/User can remove any of the listed question from the widget with a simple click into the cross `[x]` button beside each of the question.

#### I know, the question is ***WHY?***

Answer may be:

- To provide a little bit of ease. Just a simple click to his/her newly questioned Question[s] at a glance.
- Importantly, to encourage the author to *Accept* any of the answer, if it satisfy him/her.
- To encourage the author to grab attention for his/her unanswered question[s] by announcing that to Bounty.

Let's the community decide?

Comment: The definition of an open question is a question that is not closed. An open question does not mean a question without an accepted answer.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Yap, you can name it whatever you like, but the thing what I presented is what I meant it be. Like or Dislike - your opinion.

Comment: Not sure what makes you think my comment is opinionated in any way, but ok.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you can search for your own open questions [via search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3Ano):

```
user:me hasaccepted:no
```

If you want to check your questions, feel free to bookmark that search.

Second, if you want to remove a question from the list you may try the following strategies:

1. accept an answer,
2. edit to improve the question,
3. offer a bounty, or
4. delete the question (if [appropriate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155933/1438)).

These are generally desirable behaviours from the communal perspective.  Clicking a checkbox to remove a question from you personal list has no communal value whatsoever.

Finally, there are already plenty of incentives for users to monitor their own questions.  Presumably you care enough about an answer that you will check up on your questions once in a while.  Putting unanswered questions in the face of people who have moved on with their lives serves very little purpose but to leave bad feelings about the site.  It's adding insult to injury or rubbing salt in the wounds or what-have-you.

Comment: Another strategy that I sometimes use is to self-answer my question with any progress I've made.  I've even [solved my own problem](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/2585/95) that way.