# Question deleted after I posted an answer

Tags: discussion, questions

I just had a question deleted after I posted an answer.

I was under the impression that this was not possible.

[Why doesn't this GROUP BY query work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771599/why-doesnt-this-group-by-query-work/19771731#19771731)

Comment: If your answer was not upvoted then the deletion protection does not apply

Comment: This is a shame, there should be some time for people to read the answer and consider up-voting it.

Comment: I've had this happen a few times. You answer the question, they get their answer - then delete the question within minutes of you answering it.. lame i'd say.

Comment: Yeah it was annoying.

Comment: @Hogan If the deletion happened almost immediately after you posted your answer, then you could try flagging the question and asking the mods to restore it. Use the custom flag, and clearly explain why you think the question should be restored.

Comment: @Yannis If you aren't a 10k user, how do you flag the question after it's deleted?

Comment: @JoshC: You can find recently deleted answers in your answers tab; there is a link at the bottom.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Can you still see the deleted *question* though to access the flag dialogue?

Comment: @MartinSmith: Ah, perhaps not; I don't know tbh.

Comment: Hm, haven't thought of that @JoshC. I guess raising the issue on Meta is the next best thing then.

Comment: I just tried accessing a deleted answer of mine on a deleted question, and I can't see it since I don't have 10k.

Comment: You may wish to support [this proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155933/preventing-misuse-of-question-self-deletion) which suggests a short lock after a new answer is posted

Comment: I just had this happen, seconds after I provided the answer. It's total abuse of the system. It's making me think twice before answering a question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible for the question author to delete the question if there is an answer *with a positive score*.

It's also possible that the question was deleted by a 3 10k rep users, or a moderator.

Comment: But if it has no score?

Comment: @Hogan If it has a score of zero or lower then it doesn't prevent the author from deleting the question.

Comment: @Hogan - Then it can be deleted.

Answer (score 5):

On a prior question of his, someone suggested in a comment that he delete his question if he found the root cause of the problem.  I guess he now thinks that's the standard practice.

It's not a great question, but I undeleted it, since he apparently got his answer from another community member, and not on his own.