# Is it ok to delete homework questions to hide the evidence?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, homework

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292750/how-to-make-a-while-loop-that-will-plot-12-evenly-spaced-spheres-on-a-circle-of/21293247#21293247) was a perfectly good (possibly homework) question

The OP thanked me for my answer

> Thanks, you just ended my frustration! –  user3225065

and then deleted the question!

I don't think this type of behaviour adds value to the site.

---

Below is the original text of the question: (since it isn't visible to people with less than 10k reputation)

---

How do I make a while loop that will plot 12 evenly spaced spheres on a circle of radius 20x10^-10 in the y,z plane.

The actual question is as follows: -Use a while loop to consider N = 12 observation points that lie on a circle of radius 20 A in the y-z plane. One of the points should be on the +y axis. The program should determine the position of the remaining observation points, which are equally spaced around the circle.

-For each observation point, the program should calculate the electric eld and display an arrow to represent the eld. The tail of the arrow should be at the observation point, the length of the arrow should be proportional to the magnitude of the eld, and the direction of the arrow should indicate the direction of the eld. Adjust the scalefactor for the arrows to produce a reasonable graphic display.

```
******Code********
from __future__ import division, print_function
from visual import *

#Define constants
e = 1.6e-19
ke = 9e9
A2m = 1e-10
scalefactor = 1e-17

xaxis = cylinder(pos=vector(-50,0,0)*A2m, axis=vector(100,0,0)*A2m, radius=.2*A2m)
yaxis = cylinder(pos=vector(0,-50,0)*A2m, axis=vector(0,100,0)*A2m, radius=.2*A2m)
zaxis = cylinder(pos=vector(0,0,-50)*A2m, axis=vector(0,0,100)*A2m, radius=.2*A2m)

rsource=vector (0,0,0)
ion = sphere(pos=vector(0,0,0), radius=A2m, color=color.yellow)
ion.q = -e

#initial values
theta=0
robs=vector(0,20*A2m,sin(theta))


#calculations

while theta <= 2*pi:
    rate(5)
    r = robs - rsource
    rmag = mag(r)
    rhat = norm(r)
    Efield = (ke*ion.q*rhat)/(rmag**2)
    Earrow= arrow(pos=robs, axis=Efield*scalefactor, color = color.orange)
    theta = theta + (2*pi)/12
```

Comment: I've voted to undelete, but once it is open again it also needs a rollback to [revision 2](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21292750/2)

Comment: Relevant feature request to prevent immediate deletion of answered questions: [Preventing misuse of question self-deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155933/preventing-misuse-of-question-self-deletion)

Comment: @RichardTingle, thanks, I upvoted that one. I've seen it happen a few times in the past and _something_ should really be done to prevent it

Comment: 1. No, this is not ok. 2. You might be surprised how many times a day people flag questions that have *upvoted and accepted* answers for deletion. And they just shamelessly tell us "I don't want my boss/professor to see this"!  `</rant>`

Comment: This isn't just homework questions. Every day, we get flags asking for deletion of questions because the asker posted their client's proprietary code and their manager caught them at it. I always respond that we're not going to delete questions with great answers, but they can try to anonymize the variables, function names, etc. You'd think people would check *before* they posted something publicly on one of the most popular sites on the Internet, but no they don't.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No, that's not acceptable. The OP can delete questions if there are no answers or no upvoted answers, but since they've acknowledged that you've helped them, they shouldn't let the information go to waste. You deserve reputation by having the answer accepted, and the question may be helpful to future visitors too.

The OP *may* have the post disassociated from their account* if they strongly feel that it shouldn't be linked to their profile. They can flag the post and ask for a moderator to do that.

In your case you did the right thing by coming to Meta, where users with the necessary privileges can undelete the question.

<sub>* Remember that the license allows Stack Exchange to use the content you post in any way—you *never* have the right to completely remove it. That's why it can be anonymized.</sub>

Comment: But I can understand what Op's feel when people keep down-voting on the question & unable to delete question when it has a good answer & upvoted. My [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320026/xpath-query-giving-no-result) although it has good explanation I keep getting downvotes I can never able to delete my question as it has answer with a upvote :(

Comment: I can understand that downvotes don't "feel nice" but they should prompt you to improve your question if possible, not delete it because you feel ashamed for it. It's utterly disrespectful for those who have invested the time to help you and answer your question.

Comment: I have had questions down voted because people did not like me asking how to do something they disapprove off.    Sometimes sorting out the design of a system is not an option, so you have to ask about implementing a bad design and therefore you get lots of down votes.

Answer (score 13):

Actions like this demonstrate that the OP sees Stack Overflow as his or her personal helpdesk. They are wrong. It is not.

They should be educated regarding this.

Actually, this needs to be clearer in general, on the site.

Comment: That is too-common a misunderstanding, yes. You can also see it in people who ask for questions to be 'closed' once they get an answer, or who edit in an answer in their question with 'closed' or 'solved' in the title/body.